# Itemizing big xml files in Python

Tags: python, xml, xslt, lxml, elementtree

I am designing some sort of ETL pipeline, where I'd like 1st to split the input XML dataset into individual XML files related to each item. The input dataset(s) are basically exports of metadata under specific models (current example is EDM). I am rather comfortable with XSLT and was hoping to use that to avoid too much Python on this matter, which is supposedly not that complex.

I have browsed many threads, including Lisa Daly's Fast_iter (Cf. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/). I tried different approach but I always end up stuck when writing the files (either no output, or serialization issues). Looking for some seasoned feedback please ?!

## Dataset structure

```
<rdf:RDF ...many namespaces...>
    <!--ITEM1 NODE-->
    <ore:aggregates>
        <edm:ProvidedCHO rdf:about="http://some/url"/>
        <ore:Aggregation rdf:about="http://some/url">
            <...>
        </ore:Aggregation>
        <ore:Proxy rdf:about="http://some/url">
            <...>
        </ore:Proxy>
        <edm:EuropeanaAggregation rdf:about="http://some/url">
            <...>      
        </edm:EuropeanaAggregation>
    </ore:aggregates>

    <!--ITEM2 NODE-->
    <ore:aggregates>
        <...>      
    </ore:aggregates>

    <!--ITEM3 NODE-->
    <ore:aggregates>
        <...>      
    </ore:aggregates>
</rdf:RDF>
```

## Expected result

```
<!--ITEM 1-->
<rdf:RDF ...many namespaces...>
    <edm:ProvidedCHO rdf:about="http://some/url"/>
    <ore:Aggregation rdf:about="http://some/url">
        <...>
    </ore:Aggregation>
    <ore:Proxy rdf:about="http://some/url">
        <...>
    </ore:Proxy>
    <edm:EuropeanaAggregation rdf:about="http://some/url">
        <...>      
    </edm:EuropeanaAggregation>
</rdf:RDF>
```

## CURRENT TRYOUTS

### Trying to use lxml to apply an itemizing XSLT once (script+xslt)

```
from lxml import etree as ET
    dom = ET.parse(source)
    xslt = ET.parse(xsl_filename)
    transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
    newdom = transform(dom)
    print(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xsi xlink xml" version="2.0"
    xmlns:many="namespaces">

    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!--<xsl:param name="output" select="'/Users/yep/Code/+dev/test data/output/'"/>-->
    <xsl:param name="output" select="'/home/yep/data/split/'"/>
    <xsl:param name="children" select="/rdf:RDF/ore:aggregates"/>

    <!-- ROOT MATCH -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="$children">
            <xsl:call-template name="itemize"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="itemize">

            <xsl:variable name="uri" select="translate(ore:Proxy/dc:identifier, ' ', '_')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="ns"/>
            <xsl:variable name="fullOutput" select="concat($output, $uri)"/>
            <xsl:result-document href="{$fullOutput}.xml" method="xml">
                <xsl:element name="rdf:RDF">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... no output. Also tried 'write' but not working

### Trying via ETree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    root = ET.parse(source).getroot()

    # namespaces variable generated from a json file
    jsonFile = open("application/models/namespaces.json")
    jsonStr = jsonFile.read()
    namespaces = json.loads(jsonStr)

    for item in root.findall("ore:aggregates",namespaces):
        newTree = ET.parse("/home/yep/application/services/create/sample.xml")
        newroot = newTree.getroot()

        for node in item.findall("edm:ProvidedCHO",namespaces):
            newroot.append(node)
            ET.SubElement(newroot,node)

        filename = "/home/yep/data/split/" + str(i) + ".xml"
        newTree.write(filename)

TypeError: cannot serialize <Element '{http://www.europeana.eu/schemas/edm/}ProvidedCHO' at 0x7f4768a03688> (type Element)
```

I think the issue is related to the fact that I am handling namespaces not properly or maybe because I'm still an XSLT approach towards data when it is Python ... some help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Where is your XSLT which is a programming language that `lxml` parses and runs?

Comment: @Parfait here is it (ideally, it'd be nice to pass the top children node as an argument when triggering the stylesheet ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're trying to process XSLT with lxml, you're stuck with XSLT 1.0. Since 1.0 doesn't support `xsl:result-document`, you'll have to use the exlst `document` extension (which luckily lxml supports).

Here's an example...

**XML Input** (test.xml)

```xml
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://some rdf uri" xmlns:edm="http://some edm uri" xmlns:ore="http://some ore uri">
    <!--ITEM1 NODE-->
    <ore:aggregates>
        <edm:ProvidedCHO rdf:about="http://some/url">from item1</edm:ProvidedCHO>
        <ore:Aggregation rdf:about="http://some/url">from item1</ore:Aggregation>
        <ore:Proxy rdf:about="http://some/url">from item1</ore:Proxy>
        <edm:EuropeanaAggregation rdf:about="http://some/url">from item1</edm:EuropeanaAggregation>
    </ore:aggregates>

    <!--ITEM2 NODE-->
    <ore:aggregates>
        <edm:ProvidedCHO rdf:about="http://some/url">from item2</edm:ProvidedCHO>
        <ore:Aggregation rdf:about="http://some/url">from item2</ore:Aggregation>
        <ore:Proxy rdf:about="http://some/url">from item2</ore:Proxy>
        <edm:EuropeanaAggregation rdf:about="http://some/url">from item2</edm:EuropeanaAggregation>
    </ore:aggregates>

    <!--ITEM3 NODE-->
    <ore:aggregates>
        <edm:ProvidedCHO rdf:about="http://some/url">from item3</edm:ProvidedCHO>
        <ore:Aggregation rdf:about="http://some/url">from item3</ore:Aggregation>
        <ore:Proxy rdf:about="http://some/url">from item3</ore:Proxy>
        <edm:EuropeanaAggregation rdf:about="http://some/url">from item3</edm:EuropeanaAggregation>
    </ore:aggregates>
</rdf:RDF>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (test.xsl)

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".." mode="copy">
      <xsl:with-param name="target_id" select="generate-id()"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*" mode="copy">
    <xsl:param name="target_id"/>
    <exsl:document href="{$target_id}.xml" indent="yes">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|*[generate-id()=$target_id]/*"/>
      </xsl:copy>      
    </exsl:document>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("test.xml")
xslt = etree.parse("test.xsl")

tree.xslt(xslt)
```

**Output** (The filenames are based on the generated ID's so they will probably differ when running my code.)

**idm253366124.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://some_rdf_uri" xmlns:edm="http://some_edm_uri" xmlns:ore="http://some_ore_uri">
  <edm:ProvidedCHO rdf:about="http://some/url">from item1</edm:ProvidedCHO>
  <ore:Aggregation rdf:about="http://some/url">from item1</ore:Aggregation>
  <ore:Proxy rdf:about="http://some/url">from item1</ore:Proxy>
  <edm:EuropeanaAggregation rdf:about="http://some/url">from item1</edm:EuropeanaAggregation>
</rdf:RDF>
```

**idm219411756.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://some_rdf_uri" xmlns:edm="http://some_edm_uri" xmlns:ore="http://some_ore_uri">
  <edm:ProvidedCHO rdf:about="http://some/url">from item2</edm:ProvidedCHO>
  <ore:Aggregation rdf:about="http://some/url">from item2</ore:Aggregation>
  <ore:Proxy rdf:about="http://some/url">from item2</ore:Proxy>
  <edm:EuropeanaAggregation rdf:about="http://some/url">from item2</edm:EuropeanaAggregation>
</rdf:RDF>
```

**idm219410244.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://some_rdf_uri" xmlns:edm="http://some_edm_uri" xmlns:ore="http://some_ore_uri">
  <edm:ProvidedCHO rdf:about="http://some/url">from item3</edm:ProvidedCHO>
  <ore:Aggregation rdf:about="http://some/url">from item3</ore:Aggregation>
  <ore:Proxy rdf:about="http://some/url">from item3</ore:Proxy>
  <edm:EuropeanaAggregation rdf:about="http://some/url">from item3</edm:EuropeanaAggregation>
</rdf:RDF>
```

---

Update for dynamic path...

**XSLT**

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:rdf="http://some_rdf_uri" xmlns:edm="http://some_edm_uri" 
  xmlns:ore="http://some_ore_uri"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="elem_by_id" match="*" use="generate-id()"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*" name="root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/*" mode="copy">
      <xsl:with-param name="target_id" select="generate-id()"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*" mode="copy">
    <xsl:param name="target_id"/>
    <exsl:document href="temp/{$target_id}.xml" indent="yes">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|key('elem_by_id',$target_id)/*"/>
      </xsl:copy>      
    </exsl:document>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("test.xml")
xslt = etree.parse("test.xsl")

target_path = "/rdf:RDF/ore:aggregates"

try:
    elem = xslt.xpath("/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:template[@name='root']/xsl:apply-templates",
                      namespaces={"xsl": "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"})[0]
    elem.attrib["select"] = target_path
except IndexError:
    print("Could not find xsl:template to update.")

tree.xslt(xslt)
```

Comment: Thank you @daniel-haley it worked. It's a big help! Last thing, it should also be possible to pass a parameter to the xslt, for instance the xpath of the item node ? You use /*/* to pick these nodes in the xslt, but I might have to be more specific (not sure yet about the complexity of the data models I'll be handling)

Comment: @Pierre-EdouardBarrault - I don't think you can pass a parameter and have it used as an xpath instead of just a string. What you could do instead is update the XSLT with the path before processing. I added an example.

Comment: The dynamic approach is working partially ... I am using it in a Flask application and the transformation seems to time out. It's much faster with the initial version, would you know why please ?

Comment: @Pierre-EdouardBarrault - it’s most likely because of the `//*`. It would probably be faster to use an xsl:key. I should have some time in the next few hours to test it and update my answer.

Comment: @Pierre-EdouardBarrault - I updated my second XSLT (added the `xsl:key` and update the select attribute on the `xsl:copy-of`). It's faster, but I'm not sure it's fast enough for your needs. (I copied/pasted a bunch of the `ore:aggregates` in the input. With 10k of them the original stylesheet took about 6.5 minutes to finish. The new stylesheet took about 5 seconds.) If it's still too slow you might need to go with a straight python solution. (Which I can add to my answer if needed.)

Comment: Thank you so much ! That's indeed much faster. I tried with a 100Mb files and it worked in about 20s. I'll go with this approach for now because I spent already too much time on this. But it'd be great to see the full python approach because this is what I tried at the very beginning...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, consider passing a parameter to XSLT from Python using `lxml` to iterate and create separate XML files by `position()` number of each `ore:aggregate`:

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:rdf="rdf.com" 
                              xmlns:ore="ore.com" 
                              xmlns:edm="edm.com">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- XSL PARAM -->
    <xsl:param name="item_num"/>

    <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- EMPTY TEMPLATE TO REMOVE NON-SELECTED ITEMS -->        
    <xsl:template match="ore:aggregates[position()!=$item_num]"/>

    <xsl:template match="comment()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```
import lxml.etree as et

# LOAD XML AND XSL SCRIPT
ns = {"ore": "ore.com"}                    # ORE NAMESPACE
xml = et.parse('/path/to/input/xml')
xsl = et.parse('/path/to/XSLT/script.xsl')
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)

# LOOP THROUGH ALL NODE COUNTS AND PASS PARAMETER TO XSLT
ore_agg_count = len(xml.xpath('//ore:aggregates', namespaces=ns))
for i in range(ore_agg_count):
   n = et.XSLT.strparam(str(i))            # NAME OF XSL PARAMETER
   result = transform(xml, item_num=n)

   # SAVE XML TO FILE
   with open('ore_aggregates_{}.xml'.format(i), 'wb') as f:
       f.write(result)
```

Comment: Thank you @Parfait, this might be useful to bypass the current issue, I'll compare it to the other anwer